# The way Visual Studio handles backward/forward navigation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, navigation

Here is an example of backward/forward navigation in Visual Studio:
I'm in file1, I go to symbol which is in file2, then go to other symbol which is in file3.
At this point navigation works perfect - both forward and backward.
Then let's say I'm in file3 and I close it - it gets me to file2.

Here starts the dramatic difference between VS2010 and VS2013:
If I press Navigate backward in VS2010 it positions me to file1 - i.e. it is intelligent enough to understand that I closed file3 myself and it excludes it from navigation chain.
VS2013 reopens file3 instead of getting me to file1.
This is inconvenient and confusing.

Is there any way to control it?

Comment: Are you having productivity power tools add on?

Comment: Just checked: I have it in VS2010 but not in VS2013.